# Forget about the sin and cos functions, show that $(x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!+...)^2+ (1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!-x^6/6!+...)^2=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Forget about the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, are there possibly some brilliant way to show that 
$$\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots\right)^2+
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots\right)^2=1$$

?

I've thought for a long time, without making much progress. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The terms in the parenthesis are equal to $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ respectively.

Comment: Can you see "Forget about the sin and cos functions" on the first line? :)

Comment: I think there are formulas for the coefficients. Assuming there are, this would be one way to brute force calculate the limit. Show the coefficients on the left equal the coefficients on the right, so when you subtract, you only have $1$ left over. Certainly note that this is not a brilliant answer :)

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ sorry i tend to read only the titles for a lot of posts :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If we denote
$$f(x)=\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots\right)^2+
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots\right)^2$$

then by differentiation term by term we see that $f'(x)=0$ so $f(x)=f(0)=1$.

Comment: And you can differentiate term by term because they are analytic functions

Comment: This's what I call brilliant!

Comment: Brilliant, indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Both power series are even.

The coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the first power series is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)!(2n-2k+1)!}
$$
The coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the second power series is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}
$$

So the difference between the two coefficients is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k \frac{1}{k!(2n-k)!}=\frac{1}{(2n)!}(1-1)^{2n} \, .
$$

Comment: Perhaps you should mention why the coefficient of $x^0$ is 1.

Answer (score 0):

When I ask Mathematica for the series expansion for Sin[x]^2, I get:

x^2 - x^4/3 + (2 x^6)/45 - x^8/315 + (2 x^10)/14175-...

And Cos[x]^2 is:

1 - x^2 + x^4/3 - (2 x^6)/45 + x^8/315 - (2 x^10)/14175+...

So add those two expressions together, and you're left with 1.

I'm too lazy to do it, but clearly, if you manually expanded your squared terms, you ought to be left with closed form expressions for the expansions I just listed, with the immediate consequence that added together they equal 1.